# Sort an input by order of importance

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I am not a coder but understand python basics. I want my user to input a random list such as:

```
Reuters
The New York Times
The Wall Street Journal
Associated Press
Financial Times
```

and for my code to sort it based on the index postion:

```
outlet = [ 'The Wall Street Journal', 'The New York Times', 'Associated Press', 'Reuters', 'Financial Times', 'USA Today','Bloomberg','CNBC']
```

so it prints ordered and on a new line:

```
The Wall Street Journal 
The New York Times
Associated Press
Reuters
Financial Times
```

Thank you!

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
 ranking = [ 'The Wall Street Journal', 'The New York Times', 'Associated Press', 'Reuters', 'Financial Times', 'USA Today','Bloomberg','CNBC']
print('Enter new coverage:')
coverage = input()
listed = coverage.split()
print(*listed, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Which part you do not understand: how to let the user enter the list or how to sort it once it is entered? As written, your question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to know how to sort the entered list based on the rank, here is what I have: `code` ranking = [ 'The Wall Street Journal', 'The New York Times', 'Associated Press', 'Reuters', 'Financial Times', 'USA Today','Bloomberg','CNBC']
print('Enter new coverage:')
coverage = input()
listed = coverage.split()
print(*listed, sep="\n")

Comment: Please do _not_ post code in comments. Edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you have the list `a = [Reuters, The New York Times, The Wall Street Journal, Associated Press, Financial Times]` and you want to to sort it with respect to list `ranking = [ 'The Wall Street Journal', 'The New York Times', 'Associated Press', 'Reuters', 'Financial Times', 'USA Today','Bloomberg','CNBC']` you can do it by iterating through the `ranking` list and see if the list `a` has the first element of the `ranking` list, if it has the second and so on. The code would be something like this:

```
a = [Reuters, The New York Times, The Wall Street Journal, Associated Press, Financial Times]
ranking = [ 'The Wall Street Journal', 'The New York Times', 'Associated Press', 'Reuters', 'Financial Times', 'USA Today','Bloomberg','CNBC']

for element in ranking:
  for i in a:
    if i == element:
      print(i)
```

Result:

```
The Wall Street Journal
The New York Times
Associated Press
Reuters
Financial Times
```